# req.body returning empty array in a POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, body-parser

[image]I am really confused. I have been doing this for days and can't seem to find what is going on. I am using **FormData** to upload data to the database and it is always returning empty array when I `console.log(req.body);` Here is the code

**This is the frontend (React app)**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {

  const submit = () => {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append("theme", "This is the theme")
    fetch("/", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      body: data
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={ () => submit() }>submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And here is the backend

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const path = require('path')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
})


app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Port started on 5000")
})
```

Comment: Can you see on server side the request having the form data you are expecting?

Comment: Thank you so much. It has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just send data without files then send it as an JSON and not `multipart/form-data`

If you check out the `body-parser` documentation you will see that...

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
> typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
> the following modules:
>
> busboy and connect-busboy, multiparty and connect-multiparty, formidable,
> multer

You can find this note somewhere at the top of the bod-parser documentation.

If you want to send an `multipart/form-data` lets say you want to upload an file then use Multer.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

However, you need to rewrite your header to `application/json` and send and stringyfied object

Try this out:

```
  const submit = () => {
    let data = { theme: "My theme" };
    fetch("/", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is said in body-parser documentation, body-parser does not handle multipart forms.
[see docs here.](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#body-parser)

So you have to option left : either send your form data as json (assuming your not uploading a file or something ..)

or use any of the recommended alternative that you can find on the link I provided (multer being the most use as far as i know)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to upload a file that is why I am using formdata but I just sent that to show a simple example in order for me to get answers. Really appreciate for taking ur time and for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

To parse form data, you'll have to use the [bodyParser.urlencoded](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) middleware.

Add the following to your code, before you handle the POST request

BodyParser is no longer bundled with Express

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Based on my reading going back, you can also use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Below sample code is working for me. Update accodingly as per your needs

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('form');
});

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

// for parsing application/xwww-
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
//form-urlencoded

// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(upload.array()); 
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body);
   res.send("recieved your request!");
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Also note:

> A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body). This object will contain key-value pairs, where the value can be a string or array (when extended is false), or any type (when extended is true).

Comment: thank you for your comment but it is still not working

Comment: I have changed it, pls check if there is still another error

Comment: paste your updated code with suggested changes please. Did you remove `app.use(bodyParser.json())`? If not please reove and try

Comment: @obanijesuadufe if this is working for you, could you also please accept this answer?